# Need Help on SSRS SPLIT function

Tags: function, reporting-services, split

Hi All I need your advice,

1) I have a dynamic string which changes each time.

for example today the string will be `"ItemA,ItemB,ItemC"` and tomorrow it will be `"itemA,ItemB"` only.

2) I have an SSRS report which has 3 columns

3) I want to split this string `"ItemA,ItemB,ItemC"` and want to show split substrings in these 3 columns of ssrs table. the Delimiter is `","` (comma)

4) I had used

```
=Split("ItemA,ItemB,ItemC",",").GetValue(0) in the first column of the report 

=Split("ItemA,ItemB,ItemC",",").GetValue(1) in the second column of the report

=Split("ItemA,ItemB,ItemC",",").GetValue(2) in the third column of the report
```

5) everything works fine until my string is `"ItemA,ItemB,ItemC"` ,

BUT WHEN MY STRING CHANGES TO `"ItemA,ItemB"` I am seeing `"#Error"` in the third column.

I understood the error, for

`=Split("ItemA,ItemB,ItemC",",").GetValue(2)` we don't have any value because the string now has only 2 values after applying split function.

Is there any way i can avoid `#Error` in the third column.

NOTE: I have to compulsorily use 3 columns in the ssrs report.

I had tried using `=Replace(Split("ItemA,ItemB",",").GetValue(2),"#Error","NULL")`  in the third column  but that also wont worked.

Comment: Your question is very hard to read with every sentence on a newline, bits in ALLCAPS, numbering where it doesn't quite make sense, interpunction problems, etc. If you edit your question a bit it may be easier (and more pleasant) to answer it.

Comment: You could simply hide the third column if there are only two elements. It would be better if you catch this case in the sql query though, and then display the correct number of columns.

Answer (score 3):

This is similar to the [divide by zero issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322773/divide-by-zero-error-in-ssrs-report) in using IIF statements. The problem is that IIF is not an expression, it is a function with three parameters:

```
IIF(Condition, ValueIfTrue, ValueIfFalse)
```

Accordingly, ALL parameters are evaluated BEFORE being passed to the function, which results in the error because the erroneous expression is still evaluated even when the condition should mean that it isn't.

I can't see a way to use the usual workaround tha solves the problem in the divide by zero case. What we need is a real language that doesn't have this problem. Fortunately, this is availble in the form of custom code.

Do the following:

- Right-click on an area of the report surface that has no report objects
- Select Report Properties
- Click on the Code tab
- Insert the following code:

  ```
  Public Function ExtractCode(Combined As String, Position As Integer) As String
      if (Split(Combined, ",").Length >= Position) Then
          Return Split(Combined, ",").GetValue(Position-1)
      Else
          Return ""
      End If
  End Function
  ```
- Click OK and go back to the report
- Right-click on the cell you want the expression in and click Expression
- Insert the following expression:

  ```
  =Code.ExtractCode(Fields!Combo.Value, 3)
  ```

The value 3 is the "column" that you want to extract from the Combo field, so to get the second "column" you would use 2. If there isn't a column at that position, an empty string is returned.

Answer (score 0):

you could change the visibility of the 3rd column to hidden if the name returns an error

Answer (score 0):

You can append a dummy element and then split:

```
yourText = "ItemA,ItemB"

item0 = Split(yourText & ",", ",").GetValue(0)
item1 = Split(yourText & ",", ",").GetValue(1)
item2 = Split(yourText & ",", ",").GetValue(2)

item0 = ItemA
item1 = ItemB
item2 =
```